# textinput box with inline image

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Is there any way to create a textInput box for flex mobile with inline image without using textflow ?

Basically i need a text input component , so that user can just use it as normal text input box but to it images can also be entered inline with text. To enter images user can select the image from list and that image will get inserted at the current cursor position.

Comment: Do your research before asking a question: http://taskinoor.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/as3-inline-graphics-using-text-layout-framework/

Comment: i have done my research that is the reason i have mentioned that i don't want solution using tlf as it is not supported in mobile. But the link you have posted is using tlf.

Comment: You didn't mention the mobile thing in your question, now did you. You should edit your question to reflect what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at any platform, there is no user experience (as far as I've seen) that lets you add images in the text input box.  It's always been straight text, except for android which replaces certain text with icons (like :-) becomes an android icon).  I don't think your users would expect that behaviour.  If you really do need it, I would recommend you create a custom skin for your textinput box and add that feature into it, but it won't be easy to do.

Comment: Thanks, This exactly what i need, so that when typing in input box if user enters :-) then it should show an smiling image instead of :-). Can you plz give me more idea on how to do it?

Comment: I wish I could, I've never done this or thought about it before.  I guess you could overlay and image above the text.  I would also recommend you look at a project from a friend of mine called [TinyTLF](http://guyinthechair.com/tag/tinytlf/) which replaces Adobe's version and is much faster.